# Combine rows in dataframe with matching dates and sum values

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by

I have a dataframe with annual leave information. This df contains person ID, start date of leave, end date of leave and number of working days in this period. In some cases people took multiple single days off that are saved individually and I want them to be saved as one row. Also I would like to combine rows where person took days off until Friday and then days off from next Monday.

Example input:

| ID | StartDate | EndDate | WorkingDays |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-09 | 2023-10-09 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-10-10 | 2023-10-10 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-10-11 | 2023-10-11 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-10-19 | 2023-10-22 | 4 |
| 2 | 2023-10-19 | 2023-10-20 | 2 |
| 2 | 2023-10-23 | 2023-10-25 | 3 |
| 3 | 2023-10-23 | 2023-10-27 | 5 |
| 4 | 2023-10-23 | 2023-11-03 | 10 |

Expected output:

| ID | StartDate | EndDate | WorkingDays |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-09 | 2023-10-11 | 3 |
| 1 | 2023-10-19 | 2023-10-22 | 4 |
| 2 | 2023-10-19 | 2023-10-25 | 5 |
| 3 | 2023-10-23 | 2023-10-27 | 5 |
| 4 | 2023-10-23 | 2023-11-03 | 10 |

I tried to do it by adding some additional columns like time between EndDate and next StartDate and then by np.where create new values of EndDate and working days but it's not working when someone took three or more single days in a row. Also I had some problems with dropping already merged rows.

Do you have any ideas how to do it?

Also is there a possibility that I can set a threshold like for example 3 or 5 days, under which records will be merged? For example if time between end date and start date is less than 5 days then those rows will be merged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up a seconday grouper to identify the consecutive dates, taking into account the working days with a [`BusinessDay`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.BusinessDay.html) offset:

```
# day offset
N = 1

# ensure datetime type
df[['StartDate', 'EndDate']] = df[['StartDate', 'EndDate']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

# group the days by consecutive dates
# the rows must be sorted by StartDate + EndDate
group = (df['EndDate']
 .add(pd.offsets.BusinessDay(n=N))
 .groupby(df['ID'])
 .transform(lambda g: g.shift().lt(df['StartDate']).cumsum())
)

out = (df.groupby(['ID', group], as_index=False)
         .agg({'StartDate': 'min',
               'EndDate': 'max',
               'WorkingDays': 'sum'})
      )
```

Output:

```
   ID  StartDate    EndDate  WorkingDays
0   1 2023-10-09 2023-10-11            3
1   1 2023-10-19 2023-10-22            4
2   2 2023-10-19 2023-10-25            5
3   3 2023-10-23 2023-10-27            5
4   4 2023-10-23 2023-11-03           10
```

Output with `N = 6`:

```
   ID  StartDate    EndDate  WorkingDays
0   1 2023-10-09 2023-10-22            7 # 2023-10-11 and 2023-10-19
1   2 2023-10-19 2023-10-25            5 # are within 6 business days
2   3 2023-10-23 2023-10-27            5
3   4 2023-10-23 2023-11-03           10
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [pandas.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
grouped_df = pd.DataFrame()
grouped_df['StartDate'] = df.groupby('ID')['StartDate'].min()
grouped_df['EndDate'] = df.groupby('ID')['EndDate'].max()
grouped_df['WorkingDays'] = df.groupby('ID')['WorkingDays'].sum()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, maybe I wasn't 100% clear in my post but single employee can have multiple days off streak that shouldn't be merged, like for example employee with ID = 1. For this person we should have two rows, while in your solution we have just one.